# android - install apk on an actual smartphone

Tags: android, installation

I am developing an app. I have been installing an app apk on the emulator provided by the android SDK. I just wanted to see if it actually runs on android smartphone. so I installed Astro app which actually installs the app on the android smartphone, but when I tried to install, I got "Application not installed". I have no clue why it is failing. Does anybody know how to debug this installation problem?  It installs fine on the emulator. Is it because I didn't sign it? It's unsigned apk file.

Thanks.

Comment: really usefull question

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to install the app using the debugging tools - make sure the device is in debugging mode (Settings -> Applications -> Development), and then from the Android SDK directory, go to platform-tools, and there should be a program in there called adb

If you open that directory in the command-line, and run "adb install ", it should install it for you.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move for more information. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried the instruction specified on the link, but I will try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's because the apk file is not signed.

If you're running an IDE (eg Eclipse) you can connect your smartphone (debugging mode enabled) and run your project as an android application. Your apk file will be signed with a debugkey and installed on your smartphone automatically!